# Confirming the cache expiration date/time in C#

Tags: c#, caching

I have the following code set up to create a cache. In debugging, I add `cache` to the watch list, and step through the code. But when I check the properties of `cache`, in PollingInterval (only place I can see anything related to time) it shows Days as 0, and minutes as 2. I've tried this with both AbsoluteExpiration and SlidingExpiration.

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
//policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(24.0);
//policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30.0);
policy.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(2.0);

cache.Set("Clients", clients, policy);
```

I've even tried using `DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(24.0)` as the third parameter for `cache.Set(...)` instead of CacheItemPolicy.

Thanks.

Comment: [PollingInterval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.pollinginterval(v=vs.110).aspx) - _"Gets the maximum time after which the cache updates its memory statistics"_ - not how long objects are cached for.

Comment: How may I go about confirming the cache expiration time?

Comment: [Write a test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848560/asp-net-4-0-cacheitempolicy-sliding-expiration-incorrect)? Or maybe peek at it's fields with reflection? Why don't you think it's being set correct;y?

Comment: I'm trying to confirm whether the expiration timer is reset whenever we set the cache. This to know whether we can force (or reset) an expiration of the cache and update it.

Answer (score 0):

As @stuartd pointed out in the comment above, I shouldn't doubt that the expiration isn't being applied properly. I ended up checking `policy.AbsoluteExpiration` for this, and confirmed with a short enough time span that the cache expiration was indeed applying correctly. Thanks again @stuartd.